# One-shot laravel validator

Tags: laravel

I have a form where someone searches for something. Based on this form, I validate if the input is correct:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all() , array(
    'address'  =>'required', 
));

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

After this, I want to validate something else (that a result object isn't empty), which is completely unrelated to the search. In other words, it's NOT input from a form.

1) Do I create another validator to validate this? Or
2) Is there a better way to simply check this value and spawn an object that can be returned with "withErrors"?

**UPDATE**

This isn't working for me:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array( 
        'searches' => sizeof($search) 
    ) , 
    array(
        'searches'  => 'required|min:1'
    )
);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

It's not working because for some reason it's picking up that the "searches" item should only be validated "sometimes"

Comment: What is your result object (what type) ? Post relevant code of search.

Comment: Its an array. I'll post what is not working for me.

Comment: Where is your result object ? How do you get it ?

Comment: That should be relevant, but for arguments sake, let's say I call a webservice that returns results and if I can't get any results (i.e. if the object is of size 0) i need to validate that and return the result back to the view.

Comment: It depends on the result, if this is an eloquent then there is eloquent specific check, if that result is an array then you have to check it's size, so depends on the result how should you check and if it's blank then you can redirect back. Your question is not clear, if you call a web service then where do you want to send back ? To the user or to the web service.

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways. one is [**custom validator**](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules)

or there is a simpler way,

suppose,

```
private function foo()
    {
        $data = ''; //retrieved the data error here with whatever call you want to make

        return !empty($data) ? true : false;
    }
```

in the controller,

```
public function bar()
{
    if(!$this->foo())
    {
            $messages = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
                            // you should use interface here. i directly  made the object call for the sake of simplicity.
            $messages->add('custom', 'custom error');
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($messages)->withInput();
    }
}
```

in the *view*:

```
@if($errors->has('custom'))
    <p>custom error output.</p>
@endif
```

it is just the outline to give you the idea.